# Save key's and post meta data into array's - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Im using wordpress as my base and I need to output the post meta for all my posts, but only for a certain number of keys.

What I intend to do is to save a list of all my keys, that im going to use to query wordpress for metadata for that post.

Below is my code.

```
//HERE YOU CAN SEE THE KEYS IMM USING ATM
$nyckellista[] = array("ebutik_allm_bas_operativsystem" ,"--foretagsform"
  ,"ebutik_allm_bas_omsättning");

$i = 0;
//Here im trying to query the get_post_meta with my keys and save the result (it's an array aof values that it return)
foreach($nyckellista as $nyckel)
{
 $nyckellista[$i] = get_post_meta($post->ID,$nyckel,false);

 echo $i . "Nyckel:" . $nyckel[$i];
$i++;

}

 //HERE ME TRYING TO PRINT THE ARRAY CONTENTS
 $count = count ($nyckellista);
 echo $count;
 for($y=1; $y <= $count; $y++)
 {
$countmore=count($nyckellista[$y]);

for($x=1; $x <= $countmore; $x++)
{
print ($nyckellista[$y][$x] . "<br> ");

}
echo "<br>";

}
```

WHAT AM I DOING WRONG?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first line the `$nyckellista` variable is being declared implicitly as an array and then you're assigning to its first position an array of values.

Is this what you need/intend?

Edit:

Another point is, in the counts area of the code, that php arrays get numeric indexes starting at 0, not at 1 (see Example #4 in [PHP array reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php))

Comment: Hi! I know about the index this was jsut a test sample code..
I want it to save my things like this
$nyckellista[array with all my keys][the meta data for that key and post] can i do that?

Comment: well not directly, you can implode the array of keys into a string and then use the string to index the array

Comment: Let's see. If you have an `$array_of_keys = array('key_1', 'key_2', 'key_3');`, you can convert it to a string using the [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function like `$index = implode('-', $array_of_keys);` so now `$index` is equal to `'key_1-key_2-key_3'`. With that string, now you can index an array: `$nyckellista[$index] = array('metadata_1', 'metadata_2');` If you also want indexing by the metadata, you can follow the same approach as with the keys